# Error : Unfortunately My Fist App has stopped working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a chat room for an Android App.

On the first screen, a `list view` is displayed. On clicking on one of the items in `listview`, an activity is launched in whichh I am displaying two buttons called as `Chat` and `Draw`. When I click on chat I am launching another activy called as `DisplayMessageActiviy` in which there is an area for `EditText` and a button called as `Send`.

However, when I click on `Chat`, I am getting the following error ::
`Unfortunately My Fist App has stopped working`.

I am using the following lines of code :

`SingleListActivity.java` :

```
//chatMessage is the xfunction to be run on clicking on chat button
public void chatMessage(View view) 
{
    Intent intent_chat = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    //String message = editText.getText().toString();
    //intent_chat.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent_chat);
}
```

`DisplayMessageActivity.java` :

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);           

}

public void displayChat(View view) 
{
    onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatWindow);
    EditText editBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chatBox);

    String str = text.getText().toString(); 
    text.setText(str +"\n"+editBox.getText().toString());
    editBox.setText("");       

    editBox.setHint("Type in here");

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I am getting the following error in LogCat :

```
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  ... 11 more
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.example.myfirstapp.SingleListActivity.chatMessage(SingleListActivity.java:42)
01-30 10:37:40.055: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  ... 14 more
```

`AndroidManifet.xml` ::

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SingleListItem"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_single_list_item" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SingleListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_single_list" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appfirst.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Can someone help me to sort out the error ??Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I can't find the `Chat` button here. I'd say the event handler for your `Chat` button has a `null` pointer or so, but it's imnpossible to tell because the relavant code snippets are missing in your Q, unless I'm besides the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to post full stack-trace (logcat errors) and full code with your question

anyway just assumption I think problem is here (Assumption - More details needed)

```
public void displayChat(View view) 
{
    onResume();
}
```

You can never explicitly call `onResume()` in Android Activity..

Make a function which has a UI update code, write it in `displayChat(View view)`

Like,

```
public void displayChat(View view) 
{
     updateUI();
}
```

**Update:**

```
However, when I click on Chat, I am getting the following error :: Unfortunately My Fist App has stopped working
```

Are you sure you have inserted **DisplayMessageActivity** in `activity tag` of `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: and what should I write in `updatUI()` ?? Wud it not be the same as `onResume()` ??

Comment: Yes, but define `TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatWindow);
    EditText editBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chatBox);` in `onCreate()` of your activity after `setContentView()` called. And in `updateUI();` write only **logic/code** of UI update which is same as `onResume()` except view defining part.

Comment: well I had not inserted `DisplayMessageActivity` in activity tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` file .. I did that now .. but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: please correct my code .. as to what should I write in `updateUI()` and then in `onCreate` function ..

Comment: i am getting the following in LogCat :: `Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0` .. please help

Comment: please check the question once again .. i have posted the Log Cat Error too

Comment: AS I said,,, `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml` You didn't declared your `DisplayMessageActivity` in  in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Post your **AndroidManifest.xml** code.

Comment: I have posted that too now

Comment: Change this line `<activity
        android:name="com.example.appfirst.DisplayMessageActivity" ` to `<activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"`

Comment: yes that helped .. I was wrong in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Thanks a lot.